# Curl redirection not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, redirect, curl, http-referer

I want to redirect a specific page from my .in domain to my .com domain using curl and at the same time change the HTTP Referer to something else (blank).

I am using the following code :

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/random');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
curl_exec($ch);
/*$html=curl_exec($ch); - tried this, but does not work.*/
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

The URL for the above script would be something like : `http://www.example.in/random.php`
Upon navigating to the above URL where the script resides, I expect the client to be redirect to `http://www.example.com/random`. All I get is a blank page, without any error or any other data and no redirection too.

On executing the script form Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera, doesn't work. Basically, something in the script is wrong and I can't figure out what. I don't know much about Curl and this script was essentially pulled off from the Web.

Comment: Instead of saying "doesn't work", please tell us (1) what you hoped it would do and (2) exactly what it did do. In this case, presumably #1 is: you hoped that when whatever.php is requested from your server, the server would fetch the other page and return its content to the client. But what's #2? Did the client get a blank page, an error of some sort, the wrong data, or what? Can you tell whether your server fetched the example.com page? Are there any errors in your logs? What exactly happened?

Comment: Sorry about not elaborating on that fact. I have added more to the question as per your recommendation, although I haven't checked the logs.

Comment: You can't redirect using CURL - you can only proxy access. If you realy want to redirect the browser from http://www.example.in/random.php to http://www.example.com/random.php then use a 302 response either from PHP or from the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but isn't `curl()` for downloading files rather than redirection? I would use php to set the header to do a redirect.

`header("Location: www.mysite.com");`

Comment: I am aware of the PHP redirection. I was looking for a Curl solution, as from what I have read on the Internet, it is possible to change/set the HTTP referer too.